# Using PutAppend to write large data files

Tags: data-acquisition

I have a loop which computes a table, `tab`, of results at each iteration. This table is usually very large and I would like to use `PutAppend`or anything of the sort to save the data in a file and therefore saving memory. An example would look like the following:

```
Put["test.csv"];

Do[tab=RandomReal[{0,1},10];PutAppend[tab, "test.csv"],{5}]
```

When I import the data in `test.csv` for later use I do this via `data=Flatten[Import[".../test.csv","Data"],1]`. However, the list `data` is not ready to use because typical elements look e.g. like

```
In[45]:= data[[1]]

Out[45]= "{0.3105121460958056"

In[43]:= data[[2]]

Out[43]= 0.0657094

In[44]:= data[[4]]

Out[44]= " "
```

Which is a mixture of strings and reals.

So my question is: how can I append the table `tab` at each iteration of the loop to a file which later is ready to use as a list of rank two of reals?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This appears to be working:

```
Do[tab = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]; PutAppend[tab, "test123.csv"], {5}]

ReadList["test123.csv", Expression]
```

You may also wish to look at [`WriteString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WriteString.html) which will allow for complete control of what is written.

---

In a comment [Ajasja](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/745/ajasja) makes an excellent point regarding performance.  If your application is anything like the dummy above, with little data being written in each pass of a fast loop, you should be using streams.  This is somewhat less convenient in that you must remember to `Close` the stream when you are done but it is much faster.

You can use either `PutAppend` or `WriteString` with streams, though use with `PutAppend` is not well documented.  I'll show both and perform a three-way timing for comparison.

```
Do[tab = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]; PutAppend[tab, "testAppend1.csv"], {5000}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {4.8828086, Null}

```
str = OpenAppend["testAppend2.csv"];
Do[tab = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]; PutAppend[tab, str], {5000}] // AbsoluteTiming
Close[str];
```

> {0.2340004, Null}

```
str = OpenAppend["testAppend3.csv"];
Do[tab = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]; WriteString[str, ToString[tab, InputForm], "\n"], {5000}] //
  AbsoluteTiming
Close[str];
```

> {0.2028004, Null}

Notice that with `WriteString` I needed to use `ToString` -- this is because `WriteString` will convert into `OutputForm` by default, which truncates digits.

For the sake of convenience I would use `PutAppend` myself, despite the lack of documentation and the slightly slower speed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @chris Glad I could help.

Comment: @chris Also using `WriteString` and opening the file stream only once is likely to be much faster.

Comment: @Ajasja I updated my answer in response to your comment.  Please take a look and tell me if there is anything you would add.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think you included the necessary material. I'd give you another +1 if I could.