# How to save (large) data generated from simulations

Tags: simulation, data

The following is a simple example of a much larger simulation that I want to run

Define some processes

```
norTheta[mu_, sigma_] := Random[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma]];
norPi[mu_, sigma_] := Random[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma]];

thetaNext[thetaNow_] := 
thetaNow + (-lambdaTheta*(thetaNow - thetaBar)*deltaT + 
sigmaTheta*norTheta[0, 1]*Sqrt[deltaT]);
piNext[piNow_, thetaNow_] := 
piNow + (-lambdaPi*(piNow - thetaNow)*deltaT + 
sigmaPi*norPi[0, 1]*Sqrt[deltaT]);
```

Then define some parameters

```
lambdaTheta = 0.07;
thetaBar = 0.02;     
sigmaTheta = 0.012; 
lambdaPi = 1.0;        
sigmaPi = 0.0125;
```

Then simulate the system

```
steps = 252;
T = 50; 
deltaT = 1/steps; // N 
Maturity = T*steps;

process = Transpose[NestList[{  piNext[#[[1]], #[[2]]],
thetaNext[#[[2]]]} &,{0.02, 0.02}, Maturity]];
```

I have two questions: (1) what is the best MMA of repeating the above 10,000 at each loop saving the output 'process' for use later; (2) what is the fastest way of doing this?

Many thanks, 
Paul

Comment: are you familiar with `Do` and `Compile`? or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I'm not sure how Do / Compile helps here. For example, in matlab or C / java, I would loop over the above 'simulate system' block of code saving the output after T = 50 into a cell array. I would then finish by writing this cell array to a file. Is this the way one should do it in MMA ?

Comment: [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html)?

Comment: @Sjoerd , You suggest to reap/sow the simulated processes for each run, then write the resulting table to a text file?

Comment: For the "write to file" portion of your task, there's `Put[]`...

Comment: @J.M. That's useful. I could write the data from each simulation run to seperate text files names systematically for latter reading. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but it's advisable to open the file handles only once. See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13309/745

Comment: @LuapNalehw you could do that, yes. when I get time I'll write a short answer (if nobody has done anything better by then)

Comment: No, not at all. I suggested to collect 10000 runs in a table generated by `Table`. I even linked to its reference page. Don't know where in my answer I suggested to use `Reap`/`Sow`. The table itself could be saved with `DumpSave`. See also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2008/57 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/209/57